# Why does debugging break access to an AWS::Lamba::LayerVersion when using "sam invoke local"?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, vscode-debugger

This works:

`sam local invoke -t template.local.yaml -e events/event-timezone.json GetTimezoneFunction`

This does not work when trying to debug with Visual Studio Code:

`sam local invoke -t template.local.yaml -e events/event-timezone.json -d 5858 GetTimezoneFunction`

The difference is that, in the second, I get an error that the npm 'axios' module, which is defined in a separate layer used by my lambda function, is not found.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'axios'
Require stack:
 - /var/task/get-timezone.js
 - /var/runtime/UserFunction.js
 - /var/runtime/index.js
```

All I can figure is that maybe by trying to use the debugger either the resources of the layer aren't copied to the Docker runtime environment, or some file search path gets broken.

I have another lambda function which doesn't need anything from the layer, and works fine with or without the debugger.

The file with the `getTimeZone` function starts with:

`import axios from 'axios';`

This is the relevant part of `template.local.yaml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: AWS Sample

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30

Resources:
  SampleCommonLayer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs12.x
      Content: dependencies
      Description: Sample Common LayerVersion
      LayerName: SampleCommonLayer

  GetTimezoneFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: dist/get-timezone
      Handler: get-timezone.getTimezone
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Layers:
        - !Ref SampleCommonLayer
      Events:
        GetTimezone:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /get-timezone
            Method: get

Outputs:
  GetTimezoneApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for getTimezone function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/get-timezone/"
  GetTimezoneFunction:
    Description: "getTimezone Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt GetTimezoneFunction.Arn
  GetTimezoneFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for getTimezone function"
    Value: !GetAtt GetTimezoneFunctionRole.Arn
```

Here's my `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
      "name": "Debug get-timezone",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 5858,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/dist",
      "remoteRoot": "/var/task",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "preLaunchTask": "local-tz-debug"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

So far I've only found a lot of unanswered questions and a few not-quite-the-same problems while searching for an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made one of my lambda functions dump out all environment variables from `process.env`, and found a few differences between when debugging was enabled (via `-d 5858`) and when it wasn't, most notably that `NODE_PATH` wasn't defined when debugging was enabled.

I think I'd gone down the path of trying to fix `NODE_PATH` once before, based on a similar problem I'd read about elsewhere, but it didn't seem to help.

Now that I was dumping environment variables, however, I could see that my attempt to define `NODE_PATH` in a `env.json` file wasn't having any effect. That's when I discovered that SAM was ignoring any environment variable that weren't explicitly defined in my template, either as globals or for each lambda.

This fixed that problem:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30
    Environment:
      Variables:
        NODE_PATH: /opt/nodejs/node12/node_modules:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/var/runtime/node_modules
```

Once I solved that problem, then it found I needed to tweak my `launch.json` to get debugger breakpoints working for TypeScript:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
      "name": "Debug get-timezone",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 5858,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/dist/get-timezone", // <- More specific path needed
      "remoteRoot": "/var/task",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "preLaunchTask": "local-tz-debug",
      "outFiles": [ // <- Added this
        "${workspaceRoot}/dist/get-timezone/**/*.js"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true // <- Added this
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I only want the `NODE_PATH` variable defined for local testing, not for deployment, so I have a seperate `template.yaml` file without that definition for deployment. `template.yaml` also defines the `Content` for the `LayerVersion` as `nodejs.zip`, not as `dependencies`. I auto-generate `template.local.yaml` from `template.yaml` so that I don't have to maintain two separate almost-identical templates.

I hope there's a better way to do this in the future, but for now it gets the job done.